# Match submitted array fields with the MYSQL database fields to update them correctly in PHP

Tags: custom-field

I have a database table with the following schema and would like to update it correctly when a booking form is submitted with the correct matching ticket type and ticket values:

| listing_id | regular_ticket | _other_ticket[0][name] | _other_ticket[1][name] | regular_ticket_sold | _other_ticket[0][sold] | _other_ticket[1][sold] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 149 | regular-ticket | solo-ticket | group-ticket | 5 | 2 | 1 |

The array being posted after submitting the form could look like this(**when buying all the ticket types**):

`{\"listing_id\":\"149\",\"date_start\":\"2023-04-28\",\"date_end\":\"2023-04-28\",\"tickets\":[{\"ticket\":\"regular-ticket\",\"value\":\"1\"},{\"ticket\":\"solo-ticket\",\"value\":\"1\"},{\"ticket\":\"group-ticket\",\"value\":\"1\"}]}`

And like this when a user selects only **one ticket type**:

`{\"listing_id\":\"149\",\"date_start\":\"2023-04-28\",\"date_end\":\"2023-04-28\",\"tickets\":[{\"ticket\":\"solo-ticket\",\"value\":\"1\"}]}`

**What I have tried:**

```
// update tickets sold
function update_ticket_sold( $tickets, $listing_id )
    {
        $countable = array_column($tickets,'value'); //get ticket count from array
        $other_tickets = get_post_meta( $listing_id, '_other_tickets', true);
        
        if (!empty($tickets[0]['ticket']) && $tickets[0]['ticket'] == 'regular-ticket') {
           //$tickets_count =  (float) $countable[0];
           $already_sold_tickets = (int) get_post_meta($listing_id,'regular_ticket_sold',true);
           $sold_now = $already_sold_tickets + (float) $countable[0];
           update_post_meta($listing_id,'regular_ticket_sold',$sold_now);
           }

        if(isset($other_tickets) && is_array(($other_tickets))){
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($other_tickets as $key => $ticket) {
               if(in_array(($ticket['sold']),array_column($tickets,'sold'))) {
                    $column = '_other_tickets[][sold]';
                    $already_sold_tickets = (int) get_post_meta($listing_id,$column,true);
                    $sold_now = $already_sold_tickets + (float) $countable[$i];
                    update_post_meta($listing_id,$column,$sold_now);
                            $i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
```

**What I would like to achieve:**

- **regular_ticket** ticket type to update values in **regular_ticket_sold**
- **_other_ticket[0][name]** ticket type should update value in **_other_ticket[0][sold]** and
- **_other_ticket[1][name]** to **_other_ticket[1][sold]**

When the regular ticket is selected, the functions updates the database correctly but when any of the other ticket types are selected they never get updated and I get Error: Warning: Undefined array key 1 and Warning: Undefined array key 2

I have been stuck for weeks with this problem. Kindly point me in the right way.